# mysql distinct records from table with proper order

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am new to MySQL and I am using the following table.

table name is 'rd'

```
log_time                id   value1  value2   descrip

2015-09-22 12:11:02     45    0        0       short    
2015-09-16 08:02:02     15    1        3       nac  
2015-09-15 10:01:02     21    1        4       open     
2015-09-15 10:01:02     12    0        2       broke    
2015-09-15 10:01:02     21    1        4       open     
2015-09-15 10:01:02     12    0        2       broke    
2015-09-12 11:11:02     45    0        0       short
2015-09-15 12:01:02     85    2        4       under
```

I want to arrange the above table by log_time as well as i want to select distinct records as follows

```
log_time                id   value1  value2   descrip

2015-09-12 11:11:02     45    0        0       short 
2015-09-15 10:01:02     21    1        4       open
2015-09-15 10:01:02     12    0        2       broke
2015-09-15 12:01:02     85    2        4       under 
2015-09-16 08:02:02     15    1        3       nac 
2015-09-22 12:11:02     45    0        0       short
```

I tried following query,

```
SELECT distinct log_time,id,value1,value2,descrip FROM rd ORDER   BY  log_time
```

but I am not getting the expected result

```
log_time                id   value1  value2   descrip

2015-09-12 11:11:02     45    0        0       short
2015-09-15 10:01:02     12    0        2       broke
2015-09-15 10:01:02     21    1        4       open
2015-09-15 12:01:02     85    2        4       under
2015-09-16 08:02:02     15    1        3       nac 
2015-09-22 12:11:02     45    0        0       short
```

Please guide me to get the expected results.

Comment: Your query should provide the results in order by `log_time`, given the data you have in your question.

Comment: yes but the output is not i am expected

Comment: it is possible to fetch first distinct record and avoid the second duplicate record

Comment: . . My best guess then is that the `order by` is not being interpreted as part of the query.

Comment: any other possibility is available for my expected output

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your ordering by `log_time` is correct, but your ordering by `id` is not. So use `ORDER BY log_time, id DESC` and you'll get what you want.

When you specify multiple columns in an `ORDER BY` clause, SQL works from left to right determining the order. In this case, when two rows have the same `log_time` value, it will then (and only then) consider the value of `id` to decide which one comes first.

Comment: no order by id also not giving the result because the any id will take ant log_time so order by id not give correct result

Comment: it is possible distinct method to select first distinct value as one row

Comment: With respect, I don't believe you understand `ORDER BY`. Please see my edit.

Comment: yes your write but in my case  i am having 1-100 id's in that any id will take the log_time differently and we can't judge less value id will take first log_time and higher value id will take second log_time that is the problem so i am unable to give id as second field for order method

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct but you need to give second order condition so that if you are getting more than 1 record with same log_time then you can get next ordering based on that condition otherwise mysql will choose itself.

So your query should be as per below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2.... 
from table_name 
order by first_field asc/desc, 2nd_field asc/desc;
```

so as per your query-

```
SELECT distinct log_time,id,value1,value2,descrip 
FROM rd 
ORDER BY log_time ASC, id DESC;
```

Note: ASC is default ordering so you can skip ASC keyword but if you need to keep reverse ordering then must specify DESC keyword.

Comment: i can't give second field for ordering because any id can take any date_time so we can't take id as second field

Comment: thanks Zafar Malik i will try to add extra field for order by method